# extract post and address from column in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have address in in sql table and I need to extract door number, address and postCode in seperate columns

```
10 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)
```

colunms as;

```
Address => 19
road => westminister way Road
city => london
postcode => NW10 5NQ
```

I have tried following but to extract postcode, so in from following lines after 'select' PostCode gives me '(NW10 5NQ'
which in following line for postCode3, sql throw error when I trying to remove ( from string by CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address]))-1 )

### error

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

### SQL

```
select 
 ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([address]),2,CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address])))) PostCode2
  ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([address]),2, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address]))-1 )) PostCode3
  ,CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address]))-2 index
```

index in above gives me answer 8 and if I do following code, it give me correct postCode as I requested above,

```
  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([Land Description]),2, 8)) PostCode4     //==> answer ==>NW10 5NQ
```

I am not sure what I am missing here

Comment: Does the rows all in the same format?

Comment: Unless you can ensure that all addresses are always in the exact same format, that's going to fail for a big number of cases.

Comment: I totally agree with @Alejandro Unless all addresses are exactly in the same format I wouldn't even try. String manipulation is not SQL strong suit, and this is a task that might be hard even for a human, so to do it correctly you need some serious machine learning algorithms and still there is no guarantee you can do that correctly.

Comment: What about addresses that have a town and county? I.e. 12 High Street, Chelmsford, Essex (CM1 2GF). (No idea if that's a real address but definitely representative of one)

Comment: my step one is the post code

Comment: if I can remove ( from (NW10 5NQ

Comment: i know following script CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([Land Description]))-2 give me right index to use in substring but i throw error when i used this script in same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you want is:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@address),2, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(@address))-2))
```

You were close with your "postcode3" attempt but you inexplicably subtracted one instead of two from the length of the substring, even though in your "index" line you proved that subtracting two results in the desired length of 8.

PROOF:

```
DECLARE @address varchar(255);

SET @address = '10 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)'



select 
 REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@address),3,CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(@address)))) PostCode2
  ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@address),2, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(@address))-2)) PostCode3
  ,CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(@address))-2 [index]
```

produces:

```
PostCode2   PostCode3   index
n (NW10 5N  NW10 5NQ    8
```

Comment: postCode3 still throwing Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Then you're doing something different from what I've done.   Run the exact code in my "Proof" (including the declared variable as opposed to your actual table)

Comment: yh I got some other data in list not complines with above address structure hence throw error I run select top 10 and it did worked

Comment: how can I use contain() as only get perform substring if '(' exist in string

Comment: Not sure what you mean, maybe create a new question for it, so you can give more detail..